# Which highlight-group should I use for :sign define x linehl?

Tags: highlight, signs

The `sign` help says:

```
linehl={group}
        Highlighting group used for the whole line the sign is placed
        in.  Most useful is defining a background color.
```

Is there a special group I can use (like `SignRow`)? Maybe there is a way to provide a specific colour instead of a highlight group? I tried `sign define wholeline linehl=162` but it doesn't work. I'd like to use special colour for `linehl` so I want to avoid reusing any unrelated highlight group for this purpose.

The only highlight group related to `sign` I was able to find is `SignColumn` which is not what I am looking for.

Comment: Create your own and use it? For example, `:hi Foo ctermbg=162` then `:sign define x linehl=Foo`.

Comment: @muru I didn't know I can define my own groups. Thanks a lot. I'll be happy to accept it as an answer. I forgot to read `:h hi` - I just jumped straight to `:h highlight-groups`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Highlight groups are an abstraction over the colors and styles that are available in the terminal or GUI. Vim has default groups built-in (and these are referenced by the syntax plugins), and a *colorscheme* provides corresponding color / style definitions.

It is perfectly fine to define your own, custom highlight group, and then use that for commands like `:sign` and `:match`:

```
:highlight MySign ctermbg=162
:sign define wholeline linehl=MySign
```

If you switch colorschemes often, or already have found a proper highlighting in your colorscheme, you can also just *link* your new group to it:

```
:highlight link MySign Identifier
```

Comment: If muru decides to post an answer I'll mark his answer as accepted instead of this one.

Comment: @MateuszPiotrowski: Ok, fine with me. I just wanted to see this answered, and provide some more information on the topic, compared to his short comment.